# Replace part of string using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
s = 'scores:start:4.2.1.3.4.3:final:55.34.13.63.44.34'
```

I'm trying to reset the `start` scores to `0.0.0.0.0.0` so that it reads

```
scores:start:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34
```

This works:

```
re.sub('start\:(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)','0.0.0.0.0.0',s)
```

But I was looking for something more flexible to use in case the amount of scores change.

**EDIT**:
Actually my example does not work, because `start` is removed from the string

```
scores:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34
```

but I would like to keep it:

```
scores:start:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34
```

Comment: You may use: `re.sub(r'start:\d+(\.\d+)+', '0.0.0.0.0.0', s)`

Comment: @HappyPy Really? Regardless of amount of scores, you always want exactly six zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another lambda in `re.sub`:

```
import re 
s = 'scores:start:4.2.1.3.4.3:final:55.34.13.63.44.34'
pat=r'(?<=:start:)([\d.]+)(?=:final:)'

>>> re.sub(pat, lambda m: '.'.join(['0']*len(m.group(1).split('.'))), s)
scores:start:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `re.sub` with a lambda if you want to replace dot seperated numbers with same number of zeroes:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = 'scores:start:4.2.1.3.4.3:final:55.34.13.63.44.34'
>>> re.sub(r'start:\d+(?:\.\d+)+', lambda m: re.sub(r'\d+', '0', m.group()), s)
'scores:start:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34'
```

We are using regex as `start:\d+(?:\.\d+)+` to match text that starts with `start:` and followed by digits separated by dot.

In `lambda` part we replace each 1+ digit with `0` to get same number of zeroes in output as the input.

Answer (score 2):

Could replace all numbers before `final` with a zero:

```
re.sub(r'\d+(?=.*final)', '0', s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCgIhEIDhu0/hbbRiaBs3Qlh6kS5bGQmlMjMdenqTLv/h429ffdZCp8a953errJaTMWIXC3KrnCSKrqwx4AEnJAxI8ZHL@orzjBRwIjwOHRzANM5FHSeUz9UxXO5bd15w8/897CzsR8T73n8)

Or perhaps more efficient if there were many more scores:

```
re.sub(r'\d|(final.*)', lambda m: m[1] or '0', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant using the regex [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
(?:\bstart:|\G(?!^))\.?\K\d+
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bstart:` Match `start:`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\.?\K` Match an optional dot, clear the current match buffer (forget what is matched so far)
- `\d+` Match 1 or more digits (to be replaced with a 0)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zKT77Z/1)

```
import regex

s = 'scores:start:4.2.1.3.4.3:final:55.34.13.63.44.34'
pattern = r"(?:\bstart:|\G(?!^))\.?\K\d+"
print(regex.sub(pattern, '0', s))
```

Output

```
scores:start:0.0.0.0.0.0:final:55.34.13.63.44.34
```